# Specify number of linear discriminants in R MASS lda function

Tags: r

I have a matrix with 1024 features and 10000 samples with a label vector of three different classes. I use R MASS library `lda` function to compute the model and get the coefficients for linear discriminants:

```
> library (MASS)
> 
> ldamodel = lda(data$X, data$y)
> head (ldamodel$scaling)
             LD1         LD2
V5  -0.053074978  0.14565211
V6  -0.009618016 -0.11198306
V7  -0.003863230  0.28189459
V8   0.063191889 -0.26726050
V9  -0.029950632  0.16121364
V10  0.017988965 -0.01584389
...
```

The model has two linear discriminants, which is ok. But I'd like to know, if it is possible make the `lda` function create more than two linear discriminants and how to do it in R? I'm not yet very faimiliar with LDA, so I'm sorry, if this question is a statistical nonsense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

LDA finds at most $k - 1$ linear discriminants, where $k$ is the number of classes. In your data you state you have three classes hence only 2 linear discriminants can be resolved.

Comment: In addition, there are at most as many linear discriminants as there are predictors (features).

Comment: Would be nice to include this in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I could easily produce more than two `LD` so I guess here the issue is your call `lda(data$X, data$y)` or your data. What are $X$ and $y$ in your case?

To me it looks like you have 1024 *classes* and two predictors.

If `data` is a 10,000 x $m$ `data.frame` and `C` is your vector of classes (length 10,000) you have to call the function as follows

```
ldamodel <- lda(data, C)
```

Then you should see $m$ `LD`. I guess the problem is that your `data$y` has only two columns. Now if you have only two predictors, you cannot get more linear discriminants...

**EDIT:**
Sorry about this answer, I got confused between the number of classes and the number of predictors. You should see as many `LD` as `unique(C) - 1`, and not $m$. The length of each of them should be $m$. And of course, you cannot get more linear discriminants as `unique(C) - 1`.

Comment: $X$ is a matrix with 10000 rows and 1024 columns. $y$ is a factor vector of length 10000 with three different values. What did you mean by guessing that $y$ has only two columns?